# Converting the element of list which is an element of another list from string to integer

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list

There is a multi-line string:

```
mytesttring='''3
7 4
2 4 6
8 5 9 3'''
```

I am able to convert it into a list of lists whose elements is string.

```
testlist=[elements.split() for elements in mytesttring.strip().split("\n")]

print(testlist)

[['3']['7','4'],['2','4','6'],['8','5','9','3']]
```

How can we change the elements from string to an integer. So that the output will be:

```
[[3][7,4],[2,4,6],[8,5,9,3]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert to `int` within your list comprehension via `map`:

```
testlist = [list(map(int, elements.split())) for elements in \
            mytesttring.strip().split('\n')]
```

Comment: using the [map](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html) function worked.